# 6 dimensional integral by Trapezoid in Fortran using Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90, integral

I need to calculate six dimensional integrals using Trapezoid in Fortran 90 in an efficient way. Here is an example of what I need to do:

[image: The integral expression]

Where F is a numerical (e.g. not analytical) function which is to be integrated over x1 to x6, variables. I have initially coded a one dimension subroutine:

```
  SUBROUTINE trapzd(f,mass,x,nstep,deltam) 
      INTEGER nstep,i
      DOUBLE PRECISION mass(nstep+1),f(nstep+1),x,deltam
      x=0.d0
      do i=1,nstep
          x=x+deltam*(f(i)+f(i+1))/2.d0
      end do
  return
  END
```

Which seems to work fine with one dimension, however, I don't know how to scale this up to six dimensions. Can I re-use this six times, once for every dimension or shall I write a new subroutine?

If you have a *fully coded (no library/API use)* version of this in another language like Python, MATLAB or Java, I'd be very glad to have a look and get some ideas.

P.S. This is not school homework. I am a PhD student in Biomedicine and this is part of my research in modeling stem cell activities. I do not have a deep background of coding and mathematics.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi. I never use Trapezoid for >2d integrals. Do you consider something else like Monte Carlo? I'm just curious

Comment: Where did all the p(xn) go? Also, how is F given?

Comment: @ldigas: I think `F(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)` has to be given somewhere as a function. Its implementation is unrelated to this question.

Comment: @ja72 - Yes, well ... until I know more about this I'm presuming nothing. And since the OP is having difficulties solving this, I prefer to have the whole problem at hand, rather than assumptions about what is given.

Comment: F(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6) is not given  analytically. we have numerical for that. anyway I want to calculate this integral.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at the Monte Carlo Integration chapter of the GNU Scientific Library (GSL).  Which is both a library, and, since it is open source, source code that you can study.

Answer (score 1):

Look at section 4.6 of [numerical recipes for C](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html).

1. Step one is to reduce the problem using, symmetry and analytical dependencies.
2. Step two is to chain the solution like this:

   ```
   f2(x2,x3,..,x6) = Integrate(f(x,x2,x3..,x6),x,1,x1end)
   f3(x3,x4,..,x6) = Integrate(f2(x,x3,..,x6),x,1,x2end)
   f4(x4,..,x6) = ...

   f6(x6) = Integrate(I4(x,x6),x,1,x5end)        
   result = Integrate(f6(x),x,1,x6end)
   ```

Comment: I'm writing in Fortran 90. and how can I use the recipes for C for my case?

Comment: 1st you can understand the algorithm with `C` (I hope) and second you can look at section 4.6 in http://apps.nrbook.com/fortran/index.html for the `Fortran90` version.

Answer (score 0):

Direct evaluation of multiple integrals is computationally challenging. It might be better to use Monte Carlo, perhaps using importance sampling. However brute force direct integration is sometimes of interest for validation of methods.

The integration routine I use is "QuadMo" written by Luke Mo about 1970. I made it recursive and put it in a module. QuadMo refines the mesh were needed to get the requested integration accuracy. Here is a program that does an n-dimensional integral using QuadMo.

Here is the validation of the program using a Gaussian centered at 0.5 with SD 0.1 in all dimensions for nDim up to 6, using a G95 compile. It runs in a couple of seconds.

```
  nDim ans       expected       nlvl
     1 0.249     0.251      2
     2 6.185E-02 6.283E-02  2  2
     3 1.538E-02 1.575E-02  2  2  2
     4 3.826E-03 3.948E-03  2  2  2  2
     5 9.514E-04 9.896E-04  2  2  2  2  2
     6 2.366E-04 2.481E-04  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Here is the code:

```
!=======================================================================
      module QuadMo_MOD
      implicit none
      integer::QuadMo_MinLvl=6,QuadMo_MaxLvl=24
      integer,dimension(:),allocatable::QuadMo_nlvlk
      real*8::QuadMo_Tol=1d-5
      real*8,save,dimension(:),allocatable::thet
      integer,save::nDim

      abstract interface
        function QuadMoFunct_interface(thet,k)
           real*8::QuadMoFunct_interface
           real*8,intent(in)::thet
           integer,intent(in),optional::k
        end function
      end interface

      abstract interface
        function MultIntFunc_interface(thet)
           real*8::MultIntFunc_interface
           real*8,dimension(:),intent(in)::thet
        end function
      end interface

      procedure(MultIntFunc_interface),pointer :: stored_func => null()

      contains

!----------------------------------------------------------------------
      recursive function quadMoMult(funct,lower,upper,k) result(ans) 
  ! very powerful integration routine written by Luke Mo
  !  then at the Stanford Linear Accelerator Center circa 1970
  ! QuadMo_Eps is error tolerance  
  ! QuadMo_MinLvl determines initial grid of 2**(MinLvl+1) + 1 points
  !  to avoid missing a narrow peak, this may need to be increased.  
  ! QuadMo_Nlvl returns number of subinterval refinements required beyond
  ! QuadMo_MaxLvl

  ! Modified by making recursive and adding argument k
  !  for multiple integrals (GuthrieMiller@gmail.com)
      real*8::ans
      procedure(QuadMoFunct_interface) :: funct
      real*8,intent(in)::lower,upper
      integer,intent(in),optional::k
      real*8::Middle,Left,Right,eps,est,fLeft,fMiddle,fRight
     & ,fml,fmr,rombrg,coef,estl,estr,estint,area,abarea
      real*8::valint(50,2), Middlex(50), Rightx(50), fmx(50), frx(50)
     & ,fmrx(50), estrx(50), epsx(50)
      integer retrn(50),i,level
      level = 0
      QuadMo_nlvlk(k) = 0
      abarea = 0
      Left = lower
      Right = upper
      if(present(k))then
         fLeft = funct(Left,k)
         fMiddle = funct((Left+Right)/2,k)
         fRight = funct(Right,k)
      else
         fLeft = funct(Left)
         fMiddle = funct((Left+Right)/2)
         fRight = funct(Right)
      endif
      est = 0
      eps = QuadMo_Tol
  100 level = level+1
      Middle = (Left+Right)/2
      coef = Right-Left
      if(coef.ne.0) go to 150
      rombrg = est
      go to 300
  150 continue
      if(present(k))then
         fml = funct((Left+Middle)/2,k)
         fmr = funct((Middle+Right)/2,k)
      else
         fml = funct((Left+Middle)/2)
         fmr = funct((Middle+Right)/2)
      endif
      estl = (fLeft+4*fml+fMiddle)*coef
      estr = (fMiddle+4*fmr+fRight)*coef
      estint = estl+estr
      area= abs(estl)+ abs(estr)
      abarea=area+abarea- abs(est)
      if(level.ne.QuadMo_MaxLvl) go to 200
      QuadMo_nlvlk(k) = QuadMo_nlvlk(k)+1
      rombrg = estint
      go to 300
  200 if(( abs(est-estint).gt.(eps*abarea)).or.
     1(level.lt.QuadMo_MinLvl))  go to 400
      rombrg = (16*estint-est)/15
  300 level = level-1
      i = retrn(level)
      valint(level, i) = rombrg
      go to (500, 600), i
  400 retrn(level) = 1
      Middlex(level) = Middle
      Rightx(level) = Right
      fmx(level) = fMiddle
      fmrx(level) = fmr
      frx(level) = fRight
      estrx(level) = estr
      epsx(level) = eps
      eps = eps/1.4d0
      Right = Middle
      fRight = fMiddle
      fMiddle = fml
      est = estl
      go to 100
  500 retrn(level) = 2
      Left = Middlex(level)
      Right = Rightx(level)
      fLeft = fmx(level)
      fMiddle = fmrx(level)
      fRight = frx(level)
      est = estrx(level)
      eps = epsx(level)
      go to 100
  600 rombrg = valint(level,1)+valint(level,2)
      if(level.gt.1) go to 300
      ans  = rombrg /12
      end function quadMoMult
!-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      recursive function MultInt(k,func) result(ans)
      ! MultInt(nDim,func) returns multi-dimensional integral from 0 to 1
      !  in all dimensions of function func
      !  variable QuadMo_Mod: nDim needs to be set initially to number of dimensions      
      procedure(MultIntFunc_interface) :: func
      real*8::ans
      integer,intent(in)::k

      stored_func => func

      if(k.eq.nDim)then
         if(allocated(thet))deallocate(thet)
         allocate (thet(nDim))
         if(allocated(QuadMo_nlvlk))deallocate(QuadMo_nlvlk)
         allocate(QuadMo_nlvlk(nDim))
      endif

      if(k.eq.0)then
         ans=func(thet)
         return
      else
         ans=QuadMoMult(MultIntegrand,0d0,1d0,k)
      endif
      end function MultInt
!-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      recursive function MultIntegrand(thetARG,k) result(ans)
      real*8::ans
      real*8,intent(in)::thetARG
      integer,optional,intent(in)::k

      if(present(k))then
         thet(k)=thetARG
      else
         write(*,*)'MultIntegrand: not expected, k not present!'
         stop
      endif
      ans=MultInt(k-1,stored_func)
      end function MultIntegrand
!-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      end module QuadMo_MOD
!=======================================================================
      module test_MOD
      use QuadMo_MOD
      implicit none

      contains

!----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
      real*8 function func(thet) ! multidimensional function
      ! this is the function defined in nDim dimensions
      !  in this case a Gaussian centered at 0.5 with SD 0.1
      real*8,intent(in),dimension(:)::thet
      func=exp(-sum(((thet-5d-1)/1d-1)
     & *((thet-5d-1)/1d-1))/2)
      end function func
!----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
      end module test_MOD 
!=======================================================================
      ! test program to evaluate multiple integrals 
      use test_MOD
      implicit none 
      real*8::ans 

      ! these values are set for speed, not accuracy
      QuadMo_MinLvl=2
      QuadMo_MaxLvl=3
      QuadMo_Tol=1d-1

      write(*,*)'     nDim ans       expected       nlvl'
      do nDim=1,6
         ! expected answer is (0.1 sqrt(2pi))**nDim
         ans=MultInt(nDim,func)
         write(*,'(i10,2(1pg10.3),999(i3))')nDim,ans,(0.250663)**nDim
     &    ,QuadMo_nlvlk
      enddo
      end
!-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Some indentation and empty would dramatically improve readability. This is just a wall of code lines which are very difficult to study.

Answer (score 0):

```
double MultInt(int k);
double MultIntegrand(double thetARG, int k);
double quadMoMult(double(*funct)(double, int), double lower, double upper, int k);
double funkn(double *thet);

int QuadMo_MinLvl = 2;
int  QuadMo_MaxLvl = 3;
double QuadMo_Tol = 0.1;
int *QuadMo_nlvlk;
double *thet;
int nDim;


//double MultInt(int k, double(*func)(double *))
double MultInt(int k)
{

//MultInt(nDim, func) returns multi - dimensional integral from 0 to 1
//in all dimensions of function func
    double ans;

    if (k == 0) 
    {
        ans = funkn(thet);
    }
    else
    {
        ans = quadMoMult(MultIntegrand, 0.0, 1.0, k); //limits hardcoded here
    }
    return ans;
}


double MultIntegrand(double thetARG, int k)
{
    double ans;

    if (k > 0)
        thet[k] = thetARG;
    else
        printf("\n***MultIntegrand: not expected, k not present!***\n");

        //Recursive call
    //ans = MultInt(k - 1, func);
    ans = MultInt(k - 1);
    return ans;
}


double quadMoMult(double(*funct)(double, int), double lower, double upper, int k)
{
    //Integration routine written by Luke Mo
    //Stanford Linear Accelerator Center circa 1970
    //QuadMo_Eps is error tolerance
    //QuadMo_MinLvl determines initial grid of 2 * *(MinLvl + 1) + 1 points
    //to avoid missing a narrow peak, this may need to be increased.
    //QuadMo_Nlvl returns number of subinterval refinements required beyond
    //QuadMo_MaxLvl

    //Modified by making recursive and adding argument k
    //for multiple integrals(GuthrieMiller@gmail.com)

    double ans;
    double Middle, Left, Right, eps, est, fLeft, fMiddle, fRight;
    double fml, fmr, rombrg, coef, estl, estr, estint, area, abarea;
    double valint[51][3], Middlex[51], Rightx[51], fmx[51], frx[51];  //Jack up arrays
    double fmrx[51], estrx[51], epsx[51];
    int retrn[51];
    int i, level;

    level = 0;
    QuadMo_nlvlk[k] = 0;
    abarea = 0.0;
    Left = lower;
    Right = upper;
    if (k > 0)
    {
        fLeft = funct(Left, k);
        fMiddle = funct((Left + Right) / 2, k);
        fRight = funct(Right, k);
    }
    else
    {
        fLeft = funct(Left,0);
        fMiddle = funct((Left + Right) / 2,0);
        fRight = funct(Right,0);
    }
    est = 0.0;
    eps = QuadMo_Tol;
l100:
    level = level + 1;
    Middle = (Left + Right) / 2;
    coef = Right - Left;
    if (coef != 0.0)
        goto l150;
    rombrg = est;
    goto l300;
l150:
    if (k > 0)
    {
        fml = funct((Left + Middle) / 2.0, k);
        fmr = funct((Middle + Right) / 2.0, k);
    }
    else
    {
        fml = funct((Left + Middle) / 2.0, 0);
        fmr = funct((Middle + Right) / 2.0, 0);
    }
    estl = (fLeft + 4 * fml + fMiddle)*coef;
    estr = (fMiddle + 4 * fmr + fRight)*coef;
    estint = estl + estr;
    area = abs(estl) + abs(estr);
    abarea = area + abarea - abs(est);
    if (level != QuadMo_MaxLvl)
        goto l200;
    QuadMo_nlvlk[k] = QuadMo_nlvlk[k] + 1;
    rombrg = estint;
    goto l300;
l200:
    if ((abs(est - estint) > (eps*abarea)) || (level < QuadMo_MinLvl))
        goto l400;
    rombrg = (16 * estint - est) / 15;
l300:
    level = level - 1;
    i = retrn[level];
    valint[level][i] = rombrg;
    if (i == 1)
        goto l500;
    if (i == 2)
        goto l600;
l400:
    retrn[level] = 1;
    Middlex[level] = Middle;
    Rightx[level] = Right;
    fmx[level] = fMiddle;
    fmrx[level] = fmr;
    frx[level] = fRight;
    estrx[level] = estr;
    epsx[level] = eps;
    eps = eps / 1.4;
    Right = Middle;
    fRight = fMiddle;
    fMiddle = fml;
    est = estl;
    goto l100;
l500:
    retrn[level] = 2;
    Left = Middlex[level];
    Right = Rightx[level];
    fLeft = fmx[level];
    fMiddle = fmrx[level];
    fRight = frx[level];
    est = estrx[level];
    eps = epsx[level];
    goto l100;
l600:
    rombrg = valint[level][1] + valint[level][2];
    if (level > 1)
        goto l300;
    ans = rombrg / 12.0;
    return ans;
}


double funkn(double *thet)
{
    //in this case a Gaussian centered at 0.5 with SD 0.1
    double *sm;
    double sum;
    sm = new double[nDim];
    sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= nDim; i++) 
    {
        sm[i] = (thet[i] - 0.5) / 0.1;
        sm[i] *= sm[i];
        sum = sum + sm[i];
    }
    return exp(-sum / 2.0);
}


int main() {

    double ans;

    printf("\nnDim ans       expected       nlvl\n");
    for (nDim = 1; nDim <= 6; nDim++)
    {
        //expected answer is(0.1 sqrt(2pi))**nDim
        QuadMo_nlvlk = new int[nDim + 1];  //array for x values
        thet = new double[nDim + 1];  //array for x values
        ans = MultInt(nDim);
        printf("\n %d %f %f ", nDim, ans, pow((0.250663),nDim));
        for (int j=1; j<=nDim;  j++)
            printf("   %d ", QuadMo_nlvlk[nDim]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Declare relevant parameters globally

```
int QuadMo_MinLvl = 2;
int  QuadMo_MaxLvl = 3;
double QuadMo_Tol = 0.1;
int *QuadMo_nlvlk;
double *thet;
int nDim;
```

This coding is much clearer than the obfuscated antiquated fortran coding, with some tweaking the integral limits and tolerances could be parameterised!!

There are better algorithms to use with adaptive techniques and which handle singularities on the surfaces etc....

Comment: But do you know the most efficient mathematical methods to do it?? I already have N-dimensional hypercube methods much faster than this quad mo disaster!!

Comment: Why do you call something from the 1970s a disaster? It is just old, but it was good at its time. Numerical mathematics evolved a lot. The Euler method or the Crank-Nicolson method or the trapezoidal rule aren't disaster either. Also, looking at the old FORTRAN in 1970, long before FORTRAN 77 was standardized and even longer before Fortran 90,2003,2008,2018 and saying it is inadequate in comparison with C++20 is just utter nonsense.